# Convert Xml to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have project to convert xml data to mysql using netbeans and vice versa . I really dont know that well about that. Can you guys give some suggestion, please? I need your help 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

XML data can be extremely specific and may not be coherent for many XML parsers today. I would suggest you look into tools such as `SimpleXML`, `XML_Parser` or `XMLReader` to retrieve your data into a readable structure. Then, look into formatting it into MySQL manually.

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Enjoy and good luck!